# Rest.inc.php is not working under lamp

Tags: php, rest

Its a integration error on linux environment. I am developing API using Rest.inc.php and created htaccess for that API folder which follows like below.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L] 
  </IfModule>
```

Folder Architecture:
    ProjectName/backend/api.php

.htaccess available in backend directory only.

URL : http://localhost/projectname/backend/login

Appreciate your response, its happening in linux, XAMPP and Wamp in windows environment is working fine. Did i miss any configured or software which needs to install ? Guide me, its stopper for my project deployment. if it is not working entire project throws in DustBin.